# What's the maximum size of a .csv mySQL upload using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I have a simple system in which I upload a .csv file to a Laravel installation. That data is then placed within tables.

The current .csv file (made from a Google Spreadsheet) is 217KB and contains nearly 2,000 rows of data. My .csv file is expected to grow to likely something like 15,000 rows of data.

So, my question is - what's the limit regarding the size of a .csv file? My question is likely quite subjective, but if anyone with experience with limitations regarding size of upload .csv files I'd be gratefully for your thoughts/ advice.

Comment: It's limited by the php.ini upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings

Comment: skip laravel\php there is a MySQL query built for this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Thanks - @MarkBaker what's the 'limit' with effective data load times, I mean - from experience would a file of 1MB be enourmous to load effectively?

Comment: We use "chunked" uploads for large files, so that it minimises the user disruption, but allow loading of files up to 1GB.... admittedly that normally runs for several minutes in the background, but it's very much dependent on network bandwidth.... 1MB is pretty tiny really, there's websites with image files that size

Comment: Thanks! So - even 5-10MB wouldn't 'break' the system right? I'm referring to data loading times...thanks again

Comment: This post claims [65K rows in < 10 seconds](http://www.grok-interactive.com/blog/import-large-csv-into-mysql-with-php-part-1/).